# How to rollback a specific ecto migration?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What is Phoenix's equivalent of Rails'?

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently there is [no way to accomplish this](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Rollback.html).

We can rollback all the way to a specific migration using:

```
mix ecto.rollback -v 20080906120000
```

or

```
mix ecto.rollback --to 20080906120000
```

But with both syntaxes all the migrations between the current one and the specified one will be rolled back as well.

A user in the [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-rollback-a-specific-ecto-migration/3286/4) also mentioned that creating a new migration that will undo what needs to be undone will be a good way to keep history accessible.

Comment: `-v` flag is not valid anymore. 
To roll back specific migration just run `mix ecto.rollback 20080906120000`

Comment: You can also step back, which I find to be considerably easier than finding a timestamp `mix ecto.rollback --step 2`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```elixir
def rollback(version) when is_integer(version) do
  re = ~r/^#{version}_.*\.exs/
  path = Application.app_dir(:your_app, Path.join(["priv", "repo", "migrations"]))

  with {:find, "" <> file} <- {:find, Enum.find(File.ls!(path), &String.match?(&1, re))},
        {:compile, [{mod, _} | _]} <- {:compile, Code.compile_file(Path.join(path, file))},
        {:rollback, :ok} <- {:rollback, Ecto.Migrator.down(Repo, version, mod)} do
    {:ok, "Reversed migration: #{file}"}
  else
    {:find, _} -> {:error, "No migration found with version prefix: #{version}"}
    {:compile, e} -> {:error, "Problem compiling migration module: #{inspect(e)}"}
    {:rollback, e} -> {:error, "Problem reversing migration: #{inspect(e)}"}
    e -> {:error, "Something unexpected happened: #{inspect(e)}"}
  end
end
```